# Scatterplots with density and correlations

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to create correlation matrix in `ggplot2` package that will include histograms and scatterplots of included variables?

I'm looking for something similar to the following graph generated with the `gpairs()` function from the `YaleToolkit` package.
[image: gpairs]

Comment: Have you considered the `GGally` package available on CRAN?  It offers the `ggpairs` function which can generate plots similar to the one you show.  It also allows `ggplot2` and `GGally` objects to be combined in several ways.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a quick look at this :)!

Comment: Thanks @WaltS . This is exacly what I was looking for. You can post it as an answer :)